# Need Database autonumber functionality in files (Windows C#)

Tags: c#, windows, file

I need to store set of key-value pairs in a file.
values are name of persons and keys should
be auto generated and are hidden to user (like auto-number in database but I do not need DB)
how should I do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using a database?

Comment: Because the application is a Windows based CAD, I want to save each document as a file for easy sharing.
I think there is no need for Database because only one person at a time uses the current document and I don't want to install DBMS as the software installs.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is entirely under your control and only ever written to from a single process at a time, this is easy: you just keep an object containing the "current key" and increment it every time your write.

An alternative to autonumbering is to use a `Guid`, which means you don't need to keep any state - just generate a new `Guid` for every record.

Was this the kind of thing you meant, or are you effectively asking for help designing the file format? If it's the latter, you might want to think about:

- Do you need an on-disk index?
- Can you keep the entire file in-memory if you need to query it?
- Would you benefit from fixed-width fields? (If so, you should think about a fixed-width encoding as well.)
- Do you need it to be human-readable?
- Are you more interested in space or time efficiency? Is efficiency particularly important for you in the first place?